# TIFF 204x98 DPI screen dimensions

Tags: jpeg, tiff, imaging, libtiff, libtiff.net

i've TIFF page (Fax low resolution G4 CCITT.6) with this properties:

```
H:1146
W:1728
HResolution: 204 DPI
VResolution: 98 DPI
Bit : 1
```

When i view this in tiff viewer, the image is ok.
When i convert this in JPEG the image is stretched.
Only "Image & Fax Viewer" of windows show me correct TIFF and JPEG (Ms Paint Not)
What is a formula for calculation of Width and Height in pixel to show not stretched image?
Thanks
This is output image JPEG:
[image]

---

**Edit:
Uploading image, the site convert it in 96x96DPI of h&v resolution...**

Comment: The image is defined such that the pixels should be displayed twice as tall as they are wide. For viewers which ignore the resolution, the image will look squashed. The only "fix" for bad viewing software is to rewrite the image with the scanlines doubled and the resolution info updated or removed.

Comment: Must you convert it to JPEG? The output file will be much larger and blurrier. Can't you use a lossless compression like PNG or GIF that supports 1-bpp images?

Comment: I want to view a tiff in my Silverlight Application, converting it in WritableBitmap object.